# Is there more legendary pokemon in pokemon Y/X than Mewtwo Yvetal Zygrade and roaming bird pokemons?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I want to catch them all, so i need the legendaries.
I tried looking everywhere for the answers, but haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

These are all of the legendary pokémon you can catch in Kalos:

- Zapdos
- Moltres
- Articuno
- Mewtwo
- Xerneas
- Yveltal
- Zygarde
- Diancie
- Hoopa
- Volcanion

Note that the last three are only available through real-world events and are gifted to you. They are not required to "complete the pokédex" as far as the game is concerned.

Source: [Kalos pokédex](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_Kalos_Pok%C3%A9dex_number)